# Why `pathlib.Path("xxx/yyy").unlink / mkdir / rmdir` are not sync operations?

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed, pathlib

I am using python's `pathlib.Path` module, with pytorch's `DistributedDataParallel` together.

When I use multi-process using DistributedDataParallel, I delete or create a file with `Path("xxx/yyy").rmdir / .unlink / .mkdir` only in process 0 which is `local_rank: 0`.

And then the weird thing happened，it seems that the `Path("xxx/yyy").rmdir / .unlink / .mkdir` operations is not synchronous, which i means that the process in `rank0` runs but does not wait until the file opertion ends. So if there is a file check after that operation, for example `Path("xxx/yyy").parent.iterdir`, the results in `rank0` and `rank1` or other ranks are not equal, which means that `rank0` finds or does not find some files that other ranks does not find or find.

The problem has been fixed by adding a synchronous lock, the code is simple and as follows:

```
from time import sleep

def wait_to_success(fn, no=False):
    while True:
        sleep(0.01)
        if (no and not fn()) or (not no and fn()):
            break
```

And this function is used as follows:

```
remove_file_operation(filepath)
wait_to_success(filepath.exist, no=True)
```

or

```
create_file_operation(filepath)
wait_to_success(filepath.exist, no=False)
```

And it is needed to notice that the `torch.distributed.barrier()` function does not work for this problem.
So I am very confused why `pathlib.Path` operation does not wait for this operation ends?

Comment: Now we figured that this is maybe caused by the distributed file system. And sometimes maybe rank0 have set the order to the file system to create or delete the file, and rank0 will see the effect of the order, but other ranks may should wait for the distributed file system to dsitribute the order.